# Firebase Notification and Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a question about Firebase. I've developed an app with GCM implementation service and I'll be updating it to Firebase. What I would like to know is if there is any limit for sending notifications to my client?

What is the limit number of notifications in a day and for clients in a day? Google says the service is free, but there isn't any documentation of license to use it. Does anyone know about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the number of notifications you can push with fire base daily, or at least I haven't had any issues with it and Google sure didn't mention push notifications as a limited feature